# HTTP object loading Schedule

Tags: html, http, web

Consider the following HTML Page accessible by www.example.com (fictitious):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <img src="http://www.example1.com/example1.jpeg" />
    <img src="http://www.example1.com/example2.jpeg" />
    <img src="http://www.example.com/example3.jpeg" />

</body>
</html>
```

We have persitent HTTP without pipelining, we can have only one TCP connection at the same time and one object fits into one TCP segment.

Does TCP closes the connection after receiving the HTML page from www.example.com and then tries to connect to www.example1.com to load the 2 jpegs and then connects again to www.example.com to load the last jpeg or do the last jpeg loads immediately after receiving the first HTML page?

Comment: Yes HTML will open new connection to load new image file

Comment: When will HTTP and TCP do so?